# Capybara won't start the web server when 'rspec spec' is used but does it only when 'rspec spec/features' is used

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

The issue is basically described in subject. I don't really know if this problem is RSpec problem or Capybara one. I haven't found anything on the web about this issue, diving into the Capybara code didn't help me either.
I'm using the `capybara-webkit` driver.

Comment: Does it really only not start the server, or does it end correctly with 0 exaples run?

Comment: All examples fail because of server not being started.